# Google Chrome No Longer Support HTML5 Speech Input?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

Please have a look at the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
      if (event.results.length > 0) {
        q.value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
        q.form.submit();
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="http://www.example.com/search">
    <input type="search" id="q" name="q" size=60>
    <input type="button" value="Click to Speak" onclick="recognition.start()">
  </form>


</body>
</html>
```

This suppose to ask for the "allow mic" and take the voice input in Google Chrome. Here is the W3 Link - https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#examples-recognition

My Google Chrome version is *Version 35.0.1916.114 m* and it do not do the above task. However voice input works fine with www.google.com. So I would like to know whether Google dropped the support for HTML5 Voice input.

Comment: Google never supported HTML5 specification precisely, they have their own implementation. The function to construct the recognizer is webkitSpeechRecognition not SpeechRecogntion. W3C examples are not going to work. For example of working code see http://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I doubt it will work because I downloaded the page in the reference (https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html) and it didn't work. I got to know it works only for google.com, can you try the same please?